# Jenkins Join Plugin - using job builder

Tags: jenkins

I am using the [Jenkins Job Builder](http://ci.openstack.org/jenkins-job-builder/) to write my job configurations.

I noticed that I can use the [join plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin) by specifying *join-trigger* with the list of projects to be joined (http://ci.openstack.org/jenkins-job-builder/publishers.html)

However, I need to specify parameters for the join job. How can I do that ?

Comment: what parameteres are you talking about https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/37324404/join-parameterized.png ?

Comment: @Stanjer in your attachment, there is an 'Add Parameters' button. I want to similarly pass parameters to the join job in the job configuration yaml.

Comment: It's just parameters (or variables if it makes more sense for you) that you can pass to the downstream project.

Comment: I am aware of that. I just want to do the same in the jenkins job builder yaml. I configure my jobs using yaml files since it is easier to version control.